# Android - Unable to implement ValueAnimator

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm trying to animate an `ImageView` using the `ValueAnimator` class. However, the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.html) for the `ValueAnimator` class does not contain enough details(at least, for beginners). I want the `ImageView` to move rightwards(translate animation) upon clicking a `Button`. I'm using the following code but without use.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.animation.ValueAnimator;


public class TestActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private ImageView image;
    private Button animateButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        animateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        final ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, 100);
        animator.setTarget(android);

        animateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                animator.start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image: layout]

When I click on the "Animate" button, no animation takes place and the image remains as it is. I just can't figure out how to get this is thing working.  Any help regarding this issue will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, the official documentation for the ValueAnimator class does not contain enough details(at least, for beginners).

The [key bit](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html#value-animator) that you may have missed is:

> [Using a plain ValueAnimator], however, has no real effect on an object, because the ValueAnimator does not operate on objects or properties directly.

Change your `ValueAnimator` to a property animator:

```
ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(image, "x", 0f, 100f);
```

and drop the `setTarget()` line.

Or, use the simpler syntax:

```
image.animate().x(100f);
```

Comment: Okay, this method works perfectly. But, I kinda wanna stick to `ValueAnimator` class or else I won't be able to use `ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener` which is one of the primary reasons for using `ValueAnimator` over more simpler View animators at the first place. Sorry for not mentioning the same while posting the question. Any suggestions regarding this matter?

Comment: @Swap: "or else I won't be able to use ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener" -- well, since `ObjectAnimator` extends `ValueAnimator`, you may be able to use the listener anyway, though this may require chaining to a built-in one. Beyond that, you would need to call `setX()` yourself in your listener -- `ValueAnimator` alone **only** invokes the listener and does nothing else.

Comment: Yup, I can still use `ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener`. Thanks for the help!